# Wireless built-in adapter detects wireless connections but unable to connect

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a computer HP 620 with Microsoft Windows 7 SP1 32 bit. The wireless card is a Ralink RT3090 802.11/b/g/n wifi adapter (Hardware ID : PCI\VEN_1814&DEV_3090&SUBSYS_1453103C). 
The problem is that the wireless card detects the networks (WPA PSK2) but once I enter the password, I get the (unable to connect) error. The network works correctly with other devices. I tried to reinstall the driver, but I still have the same problem.
The weird thing is that I tried a USB wireless key and the pc was able to connect to the wireless networks but the built-in wifi adapter can not.
What could be the problem and what should I try ? Does the wifi external SUB key working while the built-in ralink not working (detecting networks but not connecting) means that the ralink is either damaged or there is a software fault with the driver that can’t be solved.

Thanks

Comment: Your description of the problem is extremely vague. You just say "I get the (unable to connect) error.", but that's extremely unclear. Does the error literally say "unable to connect"? Or does it indicate that you're unable to connect, possibly with different words? And are you doing anything beyond entering the password to get the error?

Comment: It indicates both. After I enter the password for the network, I get the dialog box "Windows was unable to connect" after one second. A dialog box like this : (http://i.imgur.com/jGlEHW9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The fact your computer can connect to your wireless network with one adapter and not the other strongly suggests your problem is either due to a bad wireless card or a faulty driver.

Before replacing the wireless hardware, try the following suggestions to eliminate the driver as the problem:

1. Uninstall the device in Device Manager. Let Windows delete the driver completely (if prompted) Make sure you visit Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel to remove any other software associated with the wireless card. After completely removing all traces of the software, reboot, then reinstall the driver (Note you need another way to download the driver).
2. Try different versions of the driver. Preferably you should get the driver software from HP's website, but you could try to get one directly from the wireless card manufacturer. pcidatabase.com can help with this.
3. Try a version of the driver meant for Windows Vista 32-bit.

If it still doesn't work after these steps, then I recommend replacing the wireless adapter.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried the driver from the HP official site and from the Ralink site and it's still the same problem, does that mean there is a problem with the adapter itself

Comment: Most likely. I'd definitely make replacing it your next step. One other thought: have you tried connecting to any *other* wireless networks? You want to rule out the possibility there's a conflict between your adapter and just this one particular network. Don't forget to up vote answers on super user that you find helpful.

Comment: The same problem is with other networks (I have tried with two networks, the external one works, but the internal one doesn't)

Comment: OK, at this point you've tried everything reasonable.  The next step indeed is to replace the internal wireless adapter.